# Discord.py , помогите в создание бота, я новичек в програмировании, нужна помощь в програмном коде бота, выдает ошибку?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Изучаю программирование, и столкнулся с проблемой, при вводе =инфо (команда, с префиксом "=")
выдает ошибку :

> Ignoring exception in command инфо: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 83, in wrapped
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "ds.py", line 23, in инфо
> emb.add_field(name= "Присоединился в", value= str(user.joined_at)[:16]) AttributeError: 'User' object has no
> attribute 'joined_at'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
> line 892, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 797, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 92, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'joined_at'

Сам код:

```
@Bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def инфо(ctx, user: discord.User):
    emb = discord.Embed(title= "Информация о {}".format(user.name), color= 0x39d0d6)   
    emb.add_field(name= "Ник", value= user.name) 
    emb.add_field(name= "Присоединился в", value= str(user.joined_at)[:16])
    emb.add_field(name= "ID", value= user.id)
    if user.game is not None:
        emb.add_field(name= "Game", value= user.game)
    emb.set_thumbnail(url= user.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(text= "Вызвано: {}".format(user.name), icon_url= user.avatar_url) 
    await ctx.send(embed= emb)
    await ctx.delete_message(ctx.message)
```

Comment: Ну и зачем лезть в бота для дискорда, если ты новичек в програмировании и не знаешь, что значит "AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'joined_at'"?

Comment: Это типичная ошибка для динамически типизированных языков. Попробуйте напечатать `print(type(user))` перед вызовом

Answer (score 0):

Объект типа `User` - "глобальный пользователь" бота. Т.е. общий между всеми серверами. Объекты данного типа не имеют даты входа на сервер (`Guild`), так как не привязаны к серверу.

Для получения даты входа нужен объект типа [`Member`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.Member).

`pass_context` в rewrite-версии библиотеки не существует.

```py
@Bot.command()
async def инфо(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Информация о {}".format(user.name), color=0x39d0d6)   
    emb.add_field(name="Ник", value=user.name) 
    emb.add_field(name="Присоединился в", value=str(user.joined_at)[:16])
    emb.add_field(name="ID", value=user.id)
    if user.game:
        emb.add_field(name="Game", value=user.game)
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(text="Вызвано: {}".format(user.name), icon_url=user.avatar_url) 
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await ctx.delete_message(ctx.message)
```